# iif errors on import scenario

Tags: import, acumatica

I keep getting this error on an Acumatica import scenario.

An error has occurred while the Substring(Identifier(InvoiceDate), Const(4), Const(2)) function was being executed: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length'
tr
Here is my import scenario source field code

=iif(TRIM([InvoiceDate])<>0,[invoicedate]=SubstringConcat(Substring( [InvoiceDate], 4,2),'/', Substring( [InvoiceDate],6,2 ),'/',Substring( [InvoiceDate],0,4)),[Document.DocDate])

InvoiceDate is just system date no time ie. 20190125 
In the importing data there is a 0 in this field

Comment: Are you missing quotes around the 0 in your IIF statement?
=iif(TRIM([InvoiceDate])<>'0',[invoicedate]=SubstringConcat(Substring( [InvoiceDate], 4,2),'/', Substring( [InvoiceDate],6,2 ),'/',Substring( [InvoiceDate],0,4)),[Document.DocDate])

Comment: tried this same error  - still wrestling with this simple problem - having user fix the data

Answer (score 0):

I double checked this and I think it's missing the double quotes around 0.

```
=iif(TRIM([InvoiceDate])<>"0",[invoicedate]=SubstringConcat(Substring( [InvoiceDate],
 4,2),'/', Substring( [InvoiceDate],6,2 ),'/',Substring( [InvoiceDate],0,4)),
[Document.DocDate])
```

Comment: Double quotes are not allowed in the interpreter